# using python and ruby with ispconfig3 sans Apache

Tags: nginx

I'd like to use ISPConfig3 on an Ubuntu server.  I'd like to do this thing without using Apache at all.  I'd really like to be able to set up python, ruby, php websites.

Is this possible? Specifically using python or ruby with ISPConfig3 sans Apache?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Comment: For those wondering about the closure and comment above: This is a remainder of a badly communicated cleanup campaign that was terminated by super-moderator action against a moderator. See [here on Meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8058/154390) for details.

Answer (score 1):

From their [list of supported software](http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/), it looks like you can run nginx as your HTTP server instead if you want to avoid Apache.

Comment: True, I had read that, but that same site says ruby and python were apache only...

Comment: @chiggsy Huh.. strange!  Those languages will certainly run within nginx - but it looks like you'd need to configure them outside of ispconfig, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to run Python or Ruby, but not on build-in ISPConfig (w/ apache instead it seems to have the feature)

For `Nginx` this topic examples the django-way
http://bugtracker.ispconfig.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=2933

In summary, you'll setup `uwcgi` to serve python and `nginx` to *listen* and to *proxy* uwcgi `django` or `flask` app.